# Return matching value of an input id in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, selenium-webdriver

How do i go about getting the `title` and its `href` if i input a specific id for that data  ?

- Here is a sample code in **.Json** file

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Argentina",
    "href": "https://ar.indeed.com/"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Australia",
    "href": "https://au.indeed.com/"
},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the list and compare each id with the input id.

```
    for x in json_file:
        if x['id'] == int(input_id):
            title = x['title']
            href = x['href']
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very strange, cause i've tried that before maybe i have used in or  compared input with id, anyway thank you again.